# Prevent element spacing from changing on different window/monitor sizes

Tags: html, css

How to prevent the space between the images in the following codepen from changing when viewing on different sizes monitors? The taller the monitor the more gap between them. You can also mimic the effect by resizing the window vertically.

In other words, I need the images to be locked in place without being too far apart nor stuck to each other on different monitor sizes/viewport vertical resize.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/MarwanAK10/pen/RwMLdJQ

HTML:

```
        <img id="image-470-7"  src="https://i.imgur.com/Vu6d6c8.png">
    
        <img id="image-471-7"  src="https://i.imgur.com/EC923K4.png">
    
    
    <div id="div_block-481-7">
      
    </div>
    
    <div id="div_block-482-7">
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#div_block-479-7 {
        display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 5%);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(20, 5%);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color:crimson;
}
#div_block-481-7 {
    grid-column: 1/11;
    grid-row: 1/-1; 
    width: 100%;
  background-color:brown;
}
#div_block-482-7 {
    grid-column: 11/21;
    grid-row: 1/-1; 
    width: 100%;
  background-color:violet;
}
#image-352-7{ 

    grid-column: 9/-1;
    grid-row: 4/-1;
    z-index:8;
}
#image-470-7{ 

    grid-column: 8/-1;
    grid-row: 5/-1;
    z-index:6;
}
#image-471-7{ 

    grid-column: 9/-1;
    grid-row: 12/-1;
    z-index:7;
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `<span>` and set the position to `relative`

Comment: Could you elaborate where to use the span? thanks

Comment: You would use it like this:

<span><img id="image-470-7"  src="https://i.imgur.com/Vu6d6c8.png"></span

Let me know if it works

Comment: wrapping them in a span seems to be helping. Could you explain how/why this works? So I plan for edge cases, etc... And make sure it's what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: From w3schools.com :

The <span> tag is an inline container used to mark up a part of a text, or a part of a document.

The <span> tag is easily styled by CSS or manipulated with JavaScript using the class or id attribute.

The <span> tag is much like the <div> element, but <div> is a block-level element and <span> is an inline element.

Comment: Sorry I might be missing the point. How do inline elements prevent the images from moving, but block elements allow the images to move based on the height of their container?

Comment: check this out, i think this explains what you're asking: https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_blocks.asp

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly is going on, maybe a div takes more space than needed and is stretchy, while a span is already collapsed and doesn't stretch, but anyway wrapping them in a span works lol, marking this as an accepted answer. 
Thank you

Comment: i'm glad i can be a help